# Display the searching from API

Tags: javascript, function, api

I am trying to display some pictures from a newsAPI from the value of my input field.
I am able to display single news, but it dosent change when i search. I know i need to connect the two function, but i dont know how.

```
const apiKey = "xxxx"; //API Key


input.addEventListener("keyup", function (e)  {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    let input = document.getElementById("input");
    searchNews(input.value).then((data) => {
      //display the news on the page with the help of the template literal
      console.log(data);
    });
};
});

const searchNews = async (input) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${input}&apiKey=${apiKey}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};


const displayNews = async () => {
const news = await searchNews();
 bigNews.innerHTML = `
<div class="card">
<div">
<img id="bigNewsImg" src="${news.articles[0].urlToImage}" 
class="card-img-top" 
alt="..."> 
<button onclick="favoriteArticle(id)" 
id="${news.articles[0].title}">Save</button>
  </div>
<div class="card-body">
<div class="card-title">${news.articles[0].title}</div>
<a id="${news.articles[0].url}" onclick="userArticles(id)" 
target="_blank" 
href="`${news.articles[0].url}" class="btnLink">Read more</a>`
  </div>
</div>
  `; 
};

displayNews();
```

Comment: You never do anything with the new data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `displayNews` outside the callback that will return the results for you. Your code should be modified to the following:

```js
input.addEventListener("keyup", function (e)  {
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    let input = document.getElementById("input");
    searchNews(input.value).then((data) => {
      //display the news on the page with the help of the template literal
      // console.log(data);
      displayNews(data)
    });
  };
});

const searchNews = async (input) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=${input}&apiKey=${apiKey}`
  );
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};


const displayNews = (data) => {
  // const bigNews = document.getElementById('big-news'); // or whatever you need to get the news container
 bigNews.innerHTML = `
<div class="card">
<div>
<img id="bigNewsImg" src="${news.articles[0].urlToImage}" 
class="card-img-top" 
alt="..."> 
<button onclick="favoriteArticle(id)" 
id="${news.articles[0].title}">Save</button>
  </div>
<div class="card-body">
<div class="card-title">${news.articles[0].title}</div>
<a id="${news.articles[0].url}" onclick="userArticles(id)" 
target="_blank" 
href="`${news.articles[0].url}" class="btnLink">Read more</a>`
  </div>
</div>
  `; 
};
```

You also don't need to `preventDefault` on keyup as it has no effect.